Why’s ResMed AirSense 10 spewing white flakes, out of the blue left air exhaust?
1. What’s the official term for the left blue air exhaust (left photo below)?
Monthly, I replace filter — it remains clean and white. Daily, I clean water chamber with vinegar, then refill with distilled water.
When I woke up, I saw white flakes in the water chamber (right photo). I dumped the water, again cleaned chamber, refilled with distilled water, and pushed in humidifier ― but when I turned on ResMed, I again saw these white flakes in the water chamber!
So I pulled out the water chamber. When I turned on ResMed without water chamber, I saw the Left Blue Outlet spurt out white flakes! But nothing in my bedroom changed ― last week, there weren’t these flakes!
2. Why’s ResMed suddenly spouting out these flakes? Where are these flakes from — inside the machine? What are these flakes — Buildup?


I’m voting to close this question because medical equipment maintenance isn't Home Improvement.

N.B. Certain Philips CPAP appliances have been recalled after their use resulted in multiple deaths.
According to the United States Food and Drug Administration, "The polyester-based polyurethane (PE-PUR) foam used in these devices to reduce sound and vibration can break down. If the foam breaks down, black pieces of foam, or certain chemicals that are not visible, could be breathed in or swallowed by the person using the device."
Though I know nothing about the device you're using, which might or might not be made by Philips, you might check up on that recall.
That said, this is definitely not a matter for Home Improvement (DIY) StackExchange. Don't try to repair this and continue use.

The recall was for Philips CPAP machines, not ResMed. Howeer it is certainly possible that your machine is having a similar problem Definitely contact the manufacturer and your CPAP supplier.

@Barry, agreed, and I've modified the answer accordingly.

Do not answer blatantly-off-topic questions. Answers prevent closed questions from being automatically deleted.
